# Mod devision - there are two different solutions

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[This is my working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMCx5.jpg)

The question asks us to find the solution in the form of x = k (mod 65). But I also found a solution in the form of mod (13), but they are totally different. Which one is correct? What have I done wrong?

Comment: The correct solution is 2 (mod 13), which corresponds to five different solutions (mod 65).  Those five include both 2 and 15.

Comment: 15=13×1+2 and 15= 15 + 65×0

Comment: @vadim123 Yes but the answer for that question is: 28 (mod 65). I can see where that came from but I don't understand how they get that. and really, the two solutions that I got are totally different. They represent different things !!! For the mod 13 one it contains more solution and the mod 65 less.

Comment: @RowanS The answer is 28 (mod 65).

Comment: The answer is not just 28 (mod 65), there are five answers (mod 65).